# Отследить сворачивание приложения под iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Можно ли каким-то образом отследить сворачивание и открытие приложения? Пишу плеер, хотелось бы чтобы при сворачивании приложения он останавливался, а при открытии начинал играть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `UIApplicationDelegate`: есть методы, которые вызываются в соответствующих ситуациях:

`applicationWillResignActive:` - вызывается когда приложение сворачивается

`applicationWillEnterForeground:` - вызывается когда приложение становится активным

Либо есть системные нотификейшены:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
selector:@selector(appWillResignActive:)
name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
selector:@selector(appWillTerminate:)
name:UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification object:nil];
```